# Hosting multiple applications using Azure Virtual Machine Scale Sets

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-virtual-machine, azure-vm-scale-set, azure-load-balancer

Currently we own an application (App-A) which is hosted on Service Fabric cluster using VMSS instances. The VMSS instance has a public IP which points to App-A to route customer traffic. I want to add a new application (App-B) to the same service fabric cluster. How can I use the same VMSS instance to route customer traffic between App-A and App-B?

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy AppB to listen on a different HTTP / HTTPS, that way the applications can run side by side on the same VM instance.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-service-manifest-resources

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in [reverse proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reverseproxy#reaching-microservices-via-the-reverse-proxy-from-outside-the-cluster) for this, or a more hardened product like [Traefik](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/v1.5/configuration/backends/servicefabric/).

A reverse proxy can look at the requested URL path, querystring parameters or headers, and route the request based on pre-defined rules.
E.g. `/svc1/` goes to service 1 and `/svc2/` goes to service 2.